# How to pass data from Parent app to Child app through binding parameter to the URL in Single SPA Angular?

Tags: angular, single-page-application, single-spa, single-spa-angular

I have created two apps. One is the parent app and another one is the child app. Now suppose I have created one product component in the parent app and defined the path inside the routing file.

```
{ path: 'product/:appId', component: ProductComponent }
```

so here I am mounting my child app inside the product component, and inside app.component.ts file I am like navigating to product component using router for example:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.router.navigate(['/product', 'mockApp1']);
}
```

My parent app is running on port:4200 and the child app on port: 4201.
So basically if I will type "http://localhost:4200/product/mockApp1" then it will load our child app inside the parent app and where "mockApp1" is our app id.

So now I want to access this app id inside the child app which I am passing through URL in the parent app so is it possible to get this app id inside the child application. if it is possible then how can I achieve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can simply extract it from the url by using ActivatedRoute's paramMap observable: https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#paramMap

Comment: appId is a part of the parent app so I can get this appId using ActivatedRoute's only if I am using this ActivatedRoute's in parent app but if I will try to access this appId inside child app using ActivatedRoute's then it will not work because appId parameter is part of parent app url. But currently I am using angular location or javascript location object to access the url and then extracting appId from the url.

Comment: Okay, that is right. But why do u need to extract that appId from URL anyway? If the child applications will be loaded based on that appId, then that appId cleary identifies the child application itself. Which means, you can just use it as a constant in code for each child app if necessary